# Apache 2.4 ErrorDocument for multiple subdomains

Tags: virtualhost, errordocument

we're running a large project for different customers, each has its own subdomain. Apache should not execute any script if an invalid subdomain is used. Instead, an error page should be shown.

**Working**:

this is out zzz-default.conf which is the last VHOST and matches all queries that are not catched by another VHOST.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project.example.com
        ServerAlias *.project.example.com
        Redirect 404 /
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorDocument 404 "This Subdomain does not exist."
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What's **not** working:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

This file is located in `/var/www/html/` and contains pure html, no scripts.

Our problem seems to be the redirect rule, but we need this to match all subdomains and rewrite to `/`.

If I enable this and call an invalid subdomain, I get

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered **while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request**.

Anybody knows why?

**Edit**:
The other VHOSTs are defined as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName client.project.example.com
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</VirtualHost>

Include /path/to/local/client/httpd-vufind.conf
```

There are 13 VHOSTs defined like this and then the above `zzz-default.conf` is loaded.

Comment: Check error_log for hints, it will show you which file it's trying to locate for /404.html

Comment: No. There is no entry since apache restart. There's only one 
`error.log` file. It does not get logged. In `access.log`, I see the 404 error, but no more info about what causes it.

Comment: Try this rule in your virtual host, RewriteEngine On RewriteRule . "Subdomain does not exist" [404]

Comment: That's not solving my problem, I want to have a custom, styled 404 page. Not just a text output.

Comment: And it causes an apache error. `[404]` is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the redirect rule that matches everything, including your ErrorDocument.  The solution is quite simple include the redirect in the 404 response by setting remote URL as the [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project.example.com
        ServerAlias *.project.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorDocument 404 http://project.example.com/404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hm without the `redirect` rule, my PHP application is executed even if this subdomain is not defined. I need this redirect to catch all requests to non-existent subdomains. I've added an example for the other VHOST definitions.

Comment: I guess because of my special configuration, it's not possible to have a custom 404 page here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.example.com
    ServerAlias *.project.example.com

    # CHANGED:
    # return 404 for all requests expect 404.html
    RedirectMatch 404 "^(/(?!404.html).*)"
    # use custom 404 error document
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, that the "Redirect 404 /" prevents that the 404.html itself (configured with the ErrorDocument statement) can be shown. 
This is indicated by the error message: "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."