# redirect entire virtualhost to 404 page

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect

I have a few sites hosted on an apache server. Most of them can be accessed via http and https. One of them may *only* be accessed over http. Attempts to acccess it via https must be redirected to the 404.php page (*except* for attempts to access the error page itself - those should be allowed).

I can get a custom text message to appear with the ErrorDocument directive, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to send the users to the 404 page. Here's what the config looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver
    ServerAlias myserver
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificatefile.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/keyfile.pem
    Include /etc/ssl-apache.conf
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/website

    Redirect 404 /

    # This works!
    ErrorDocument 404 "Not here!"

    # This tries to redirect to the path to the 404.php file but does *not* work
    #ErrorDocument 404  /wordpress/wp-content/themes/Theme1/404.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/usr/local/website/html/wordpress">
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
  # required for apache 2.4+
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  Options +Includes
  XBitHack on
  # allows CORS for static content
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Trying to redirect to the 404.php using ErrorDocument results in:

> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I also tried `ErrorDocument 404  https://myserver/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Theme1/404.php` But that resulted in "too many redirects".

How can I get all requests to this VirtualHost to be redirected to the custom 404 page?

Comment: Check out this answer from a question yesterday - you'll just need to change the actual URL it redirects to.  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107186/configure-apache-to-redirect-all-requests-to-index-html/107187?noredirect=1#comment136754_107187

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/775570/apache-2-4-errordocument-for-multiple-subdomains/999619#999619 For answer see https://serverfault.com/a/999619/174375

Answer (score -1):

Remove the line:

```
Redirect 404 /
```

And use your original:

```
ErrorDocument 404  https://myserver/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Theme1/404.php
```

Comment: That's a good point - I think my wording was not clear. I don't want to redirect them to http://....404.php, I want everything to redirect to https://...404.php - *except* for attempts to access that error page itself.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Try my edit.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be doing anything. I think `ErrorDocument` needs to work with something that generates the error code. I was using `Redirect 404 /` to do that. Removing it just results in content from the next virtualhost on 443 to be returned.